# Selection of certain columns in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table name TABLE1 having 4 columns (ID, LINE, COST, CODE)

```
  CREATE TABLE TABLE1 ( ID NUMBER(4),  LINE NUMBER(3), COST NUMBER(4), CODE VARCHAR2(3) );

  INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(101, 1, 40, 'ABC' );
  INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(101, 1, 50, 'DEF' );
  INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(102, 2, 30, 'CDE' );
  INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(102, 2, 20, 'ECD' );
  INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 3, 5, 'BCD' );
  INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 3, 5, 'BCD' );

  ID     LINE   COST    CODE
  --------------------------
  101     1     40       ABC
  101     1     50       DEF
  102     2     30       CDE
  102     2     20       ECD
  103     3     10       BCD
```

From the above table you can see that I have taken a sum of cost of each ID with respective to each LINE...

```
 For ID = 101 and LINE = 1 -> SUM(COST) = 40+50 = 90 
 For ID = 102 and LINE = 2 -> SUM(COST) = 30+20 = 50
 For ID = 103 and LINE = 3 -> SUM(COST) = 10 = 10
```

---

I have a TABLE2 having 6 columns (ID,LINE, COST_PR, PR_CODE, COST_SC,SC_CODE)

```
 CREATE TABLE TABLE2 ( ID NUMBER(4), LINE NUMBER(3), COST_PR NUMBER(4), PR_CODE VARCHAR2(3), COST_SC NUMBER(4), SC_CODE VARCHAR2(3) );

 INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(101, 1, 90, 'ABC', 100, 'CBA');
 INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(102, 2, 60, 'CDE', 50,  'EDC');
 INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(103, 3, 10, 'BCD', 10,  'BCD');

 ID    LINE    COST_PR    PR_CODE    COST_SC     SC_CODE
 --------------------------------------------------------
 101    1       90          ABC       100         CBA
 102    2       60          CDE        50         EDC
 103    3       10          BCD        10         BCD
```

---

I have a TABLE3 with 2 columns (SEC, PIN)

```
 CREATE TABLE TABLE3( SEC VARCHAR2(3), PIN VARCHAR2(2) );

 INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES ('ABC', 'A1' );
 INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES ('DEF', 'A2' );
 INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES ('CDE', 'A3' );
 INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES ('ECD', 'A4' );
 INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES ('BCD', 'A5' );
 INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES ('EDC', 'A7' );
 INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES ('CBA', 'A8' );
```

The resultant table be like

```
 ID   LINE      PR_CODE  PR_PIN    SC_CODE  SC_PIN  
---------------------------------------------------
101    1         ABC       A1      CBA       A8
101    1         DEF       A2      CBA       A8
102    2         CDE       A3      CDE       A3
102    2         CDE       A3      ECD       A4
103    3         BCD       A5      BCD       A5
```

The above resultant logic is

```
 Case1: From TABLE1, For ID = 101 & LINE = 1, SUM(COST) = 40+50 = 90
     we need to compare this SUM(COST) with COST_PR and COST_SC of TABLE2,
    In this case, SUM(COST) = COST_PR 
    so we need to populate CODE values from TABLE1 in PR_CODE columns and populate SC_CODE 
    values from TABLE2 as it is (You can see in first 2 rows of resultant table)

 Case2: From TABLE1, For ID = 102 & LINE = 2, SUM(COST) = 30+20 = 50
     we need to compare this SUM(COST) with COST_PR and COST_SC of TABLE2,
    In this case, SUM(COST) = COST_SC 
    so we need to populate CODE values from TABLE1 in SC_CODE columns and populate PR_CODE 
    values from TABLE2 as it is (You can see in 3rd & 4th rows of resultant table)

 Case3: From TABLE1, For ID = 103 & LINE = 3, SUM(COST) = 10
     we need to compare this SUM(COST) with COST_PR and COST_SC of TABLE2,
    In this case, SUM(COST) = COST_PR = COST_SC 
    so we need to populate CODE values from TABLE1 in PR_CODE columns  and SC_CODE 
    columns  (You can see in last row of resultant table)

 PR_PIN and SC_PIN is populated by SEC column values of TABLE3 with PR_CODE and SC_CODE (PR_CODE = SEC and also SC_CODE = SEC)
```

Comment: You said in rows 3rd & 4th `populate PR_CODE values from TABLE2 as it is` but in your expected result, 3rd & 4th row have different `PR_CODE`, and `SC_CODE` is not as `CODE` in table1. Is it a typo?

Comment: What if SUM(COST) is not equal to both COST_PR  AND COST_SC ?

Comment: Hi...You are right..I have edited resultant table

Comment: I have edited  the question with two columns of new table and tried using CASE WHEN statement for populating PR_PIN and SC_PIN...I was getting wrong

Comment: in your data from `table3`, `SEC = 'ABC'` give pin `A1` and `A6`, why do your expected result only have `ABC - A1`?

Comment: Tying mistake in TABLE3...I have removed that insert statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this query to return result as your describe logic, assume that your expected result is typo as I comment

```
WITH tmp1 AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT t.*, 
        SUM(cost) OVER (PARTITION BY id, line) AS sum_code
    FROM table1 t 
)
SELECT t1.id, t1.line,
    CASE 
        WHEN t2.cost_pr = t1.sum_code THEN t1.code 
        ELSE t2.pr_code 
    END AS pr_code,
    CASE 
        WHEN t2.cost_sc = t1.sum_code THEN t1.code 
        ELSE t2.sc_code 
    END AS sc_code
FROM tmp1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.line = t2.line
ORDER BY t1.id, t1.line;
```

Tested in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c0c6/6)

With your edited question that add `table3`, you could either use my first query as a CTE and join with `table3` two times by `pr_code` and `sc_code` each,
or if you want to use `CASE` instead, then join with `table3` three times as follow:

```
WITH tmp1 AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT t.*, 
        SUM(cost) OVER (PARTITION BY id, line) AS sum_code
    FROM table1 t 
)
SELECT t1.id, t1.line,
    CASE 
        WHEN t2.cost_pr = t1.sum_code THEN t1.code 
        ELSE t2.pr_code 
    END AS pr_code,
    CASE 
        WHEN t2.cost_pr = t1.sum_code THEN t31.pin 
        ELSE t32.pin
    END AS pr_pin,
    CASE 
        WHEN t2.cost_sc = t1.sum_code THEN t1.code 
        ELSE t2.sc_code 
    END AS sc_code,
    CASE 
        WHEN t2.cost_sc = t1.sum_code THEN t31.pin
        ELSE t33.pin 
    END AS sc_pin
FROM tmp1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.line = t2.line
INNER JOIN table3 t31
ON t1.code = t31.sec
INNER JOIN table3 t32
ON t2.pr_code = t32.sec 
INNER JOIN table3 t33
ON t2.sc_code = t33.sec 
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 5;
```

Tested in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8785b2/3)

Comment: It working as expected and I will let you know about the other case i.e if SUM(COST) is not equal to any of the them in TABLE2...I will approve this answer today or by tmrw if this case over...Thanks for your effort @Pham X.Bach

Comment: can you look into this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485633/oracle-query-not-able-to-populate-pr-pin-and-sc-pin-columns-with-below-query

Comment: What is the last line in query : ORDER BY 1,2,3,5?

Comment: @impstuffsforcse That is colum index in `SELECT`, for e.g `SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4... ORDER BY 3, 1, 4;` is same as `...ORDER BY col3, col1, col4;`

Comment: @ Pham X. Bach  Can you look into this link (it is the variation of same question you explained earlier): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68550482/select-columns-as-shown-in-resultant-table-oracle-not-working-as-expected